# Prove: if every neighborhood of $p$ contains a point of $X$ different from $p$ itself, every neighorhood of $p$ contains an infinite subset of $X$.

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

Prove: if every neighborhood of $p \in \mathbb{R}$ contains a point of $X\subset \mathbb{R}$ different from $p$ itself, every neighorhood of $p$ contains an infinite subset of $X$.
This is from the limit point definition on my textbook. It only talked about Dedekind's definition of infinity and said we were not going to use AC, so I guess the "infinite subset of X" in the title means "Dedekind-infinite subset of X". And "neighborhood" of $p\in\mathbb{R}$ means $(p-\epsilon, p+\epsilon)$, or equivalently any open interval containing $p$.
Every anwser I found on the Web just starts with "if it's finite then it's $\{s_1, s_2..,s_n\}$", which doesn't seems true without AC according to my short visit on Wikipedia.
I tried to construct the bijection $f$ by map a point $p_1$ to a point $p_2$ closer to $p$, $p_2$ to an even closer point $p_3$ (Every neighborhood of $p$ contains a point of  $X$ different from p itself, so a closer point always exists). But before the definition of $f$ is complete, I can't say where $p_2$ is going to be; it's a circular definition. I'll need an auxiliary function $g$, and define $f(p_n)$ as $g^n(p_1)$. The problem is that constructing $g$ seems to require AC.
Is it the case that every Dedekind-finite indeed **can** be enumerated like $\{s_1, s_2..,s_n\}$? That would make the problem a very obvious one.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry I don't know what a metric space is. I looked it up on Wikipedia and I guess it is for metric space. X is a subset of R. I'll add that to the description.

Comment: What is the definition of "neighborhood" that your text uses? That should make the context very clear to us, and enable us to answer the question definitively.

Comment: @CameronBuie A neighborhood of $p\in\mathbb{R}$ means $(p-\epsilon, p+\epsilon)$, or equivalently any open interval containing $p$. I've added it to the description too.

Comment: In ZF we can prove that any infinite Dedekind-finite set of real numbers has to be densely ordered.

Comment: Proving this by contradiction seems unnecessary. If $x$ and $y$ are in $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$, then so is $y_1 = (x+y)/2$, $y_2 = (x+y_1)/2$, and so on. I am not used to subtle arguments about whether a set is infinite, but this seems obviously so? Edit: Sorry, i only read the first part. This approach is obviously what you suggest with $g$.

Comment: "Every anwser I found on the Web just starts with "if it's finite then it's {s1,s2..,sn}", which doesn't seems true without AC according to my short visit on Wikipedia." - There is no AC needed to show this. Making a finite number of arbitrary choices is provable from the other axioms. AC only is necessary when you need to make an infinite number of arbitrary choices.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I think OP's issue is not that finite sets can be enumerated in this way. It is not clear to them that the negation of "Dedekind infinite" (which is the book's definition of "infinite") is the usual definition of "finite" (can be put in bijection with $\{1,\ldots, n\}$). So where the book starts the proof by contradiction with "if it's finite" the OP sees a gap between "it's not infinite" and "it's finite".

Comment: @preferred_anon - yes, and that is exactly what my comment is addressing. Like the OP, when I said "finite", I meant it in the Dedekind sense. Quite obviously, "finite" in the sense of "bijection to an initial set of naturals" does imply its $\{s_1,\dots,s_n\}$ since that is exactly a bijection to an initial set of naturals. So it seemed to me that was not the confusion, and I pointed out that proving the equivalence of the two definitions does not in fact require the Axiom of Choice, contrary to what the OP believed based on their reading of Wikipedia.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Ok! In that case I don't understand where your comment explains this. I don't know how you can prove that a non-Dedekind-infinite set is finite by making only finitely many choices. I can see it by the contrapositive, since you can construct a countably infinite subset of a Dedekind-infinite set (but this requires Choice). Moreover the Wikipedia article claims there are models of ZF with infinite Dedekind-finite sets, which makes it sound like your proof cannot exist. Could you write it out as an answer, or provide a reference?

Comment: @PaulSinclair I don't see how can I make this choice for a Dedekind-finite set. If it can be enumerated, obviously just choose the $s_1$, but to prove that I'll need, as in the description, an auxiliary function $g$ to define the bejection. $g$ is essentially a relation $r \subset \mathcal{P}(S)\times S$, where $S$ is the Dedekind-finite set. To construct these pairs, I'm back to choice function again.

Comment: @preferred_anon Yeah! That there exists an infinite Dedekind-finite set in ZF was exactly what made wonder. That seems to imply not every Dedekind-finite can be enumerated. I wonder whether the restriction that this Dedekind-finite set consists of only real numbers might help, as it'd be very easy if the set was a subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an outline of an approach by contrapositive:

- Suppose that there is a point $p$ with some neighborhood containing only finitely-many points of $X$ that are different from $p$. That is, suppose that there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $Y:=X\cap(p-\varepsilon,p+\varepsilon)$ contains only finitely many points $y$ such that $y\neq p.$
- Consequently, the set $Z:=\{y\in Y: y\neq p\}$ is finite, and so by the Axiom of Replacement, the set $D:=\bigl\{|z-p|:z\in Z\bigr\}$ is finite. Moreover, $D$ consists only of positive numbers, so since it's finite, then either it's empty (in which case we're done), or it has a minimum, say $\delta>0.$
- Note that for any $z\in Z,$ we must have $|z-p|<\varepsilon,$ and so $\delta<\varepsilon.$
- Now, consider $X\cap(p-\delta,p+\delta),$ and show that if this set contains any point at all, then that point is exactly $p.$

---

The above is assuming that by *finite*, we mean "injectable into, but not in bijection with, $\Bbb N.$"

If instead we mean "not in bijection with a proper subset of itself," then we have a bit of a problem. Many results in real analysis rely on some Choice principle--though in many cases, quite a weak one. In this case, we need only the incredibly weak Choice principle that "Dedekind-finite=finite" (equivalently, "every infinite set has a countably-infinite subset") in order for the result to work. Many others require something stronger, such as the much stronger Principle of Dependent Choices, or the somewhat stronger Axiom of Countable Choice. Very few results in real analysis (to my knowledge) require the full strength of $\mathsf{AC}$ to prove, and this isn't one of them.

Comment: How can we prove that if D consists only of positive numbers, it has a minimum? I searched on the Web but only find proofs with the same "if it's finite then it's $\{s_1,s_2..,s_n\}$". So I met again the problem of proving that a Dedekind-finite set can be enumerated like that without AC. Or is this an intrinsic problem of Dedekind's definition?

Comment: We can't in general prove that if a set consists only of positive numbers, then it has a minimum. Consider $(0,1),$ for example, which consists of all positive numbers less than $1,$ and has no minimum. However, I did just notice a flaw in my outline, and also that I didn't address your question regarding Dedekind-finite versus the more standard definition. I'll adjust accordingly.

Comment: Oh thank you! The original text in my textbook (Zorich's _Mathematical Analysis_ uses "infinite" and I suppose it's Dedekind-infinite because it's the only definition.

Comment: By the way despite the book says we won't use AC throughout it, it did mention either $|X| \le |Y|$ or $|Y| \le |X|$ is true, which can be used to prove Dedekind-finite=finite.  Does that need AC?

Comment: *because I suppose it's Dedekind-infinite because it's the only definition the book mentioned. I tried to type a newline and accidentally posted it.

Comment: That's hilarious! If we assume that $\mathsf{AC}$ fails to hold, then there are two sets $X$ and $Y$ such that $|X|\neq|Y|,$ $|X|\not<|Y|,$ and $|Y|\not<|X|.$ So apparently, your text assumes the Axiom of Choice, after all!